# Can complex allegories refer to another thing than a specific event or story?

Tags: allegory

A simple allegory typically uses one or a few symbols or metaphors to represent a single idea or moral lesson. For example, in Aesop's fable "The Tortoise and the Hare," the tortoise represents perseverance and steady effort, while the hare represents overconfidence and complacency. The story is a simple allegory about the importance of perseverance and the dangers of overconfidence.

The story of "Animal Farm" is a complex allegory that represents the events leading up to the Russian Revolution of 1917 and the early years of the Soviet Union. The various animal characters and their actions represent different historical figures and events, such as the pig Napoleon representing Joseph Stalin, the horse Boxer representing the working class, and the dog army representing the Soviet secret police.

Now, the question is whether complex allegories always refer to a complex story or event, because it seems that the simple allegory can refer to a simple theme rather than en event like the events leading up to the Russian Revolution. Can you give examples?

Comment: I think you'd have to define what you mean by "simple" and "complex". Simple stories can be "complexly" allegorical, with enough interpretation, (Camus, The Stranger) while complex stories can be "simply" allegorical (Stephenson, Anathem).

Comment: @veryverde it seems like their definition is only based on the _quantity_ of symbols that are used...

Comment: My question is why you are distinguishing between _simple_ and _complex_ allegories at all. Why not just ask "can allegories refer to multiple events"? Is this not the same question, or am I misunderstanding you?